# Add to queue from Azure Automation

Tags: azure

Is it possible to add a message to a service bus or queue from Azure Automation? I can't see any cmdlets for doing this, just to manage the resources. I want to another system to be notified when something is done.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure automation will just run powershell like it would on your own machine.  Unfortunately, out of the box, only certain Azure powershell modules are surfaced.  You can easily add your own modules to Azure Automation.  If you want to add all of AzureRM for example, navigate to the [powershell gallery Azure RM Page](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/4.1.0) and click on the deploy to azure automation button.  This will add the libraries and then you can use the [Azure storage cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-powershell-guide-full#how-to-manage-azure-queues-and-queue-messages) as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!